# "unable to find a version of the runtime to run this application .net framework initialization error" after install

Tags: .net, wix

I have a .net project which is currently set to utilise 3.5 of the framework, but for some reason all installs of the app seem to be broken now. I believe its related to either SP1 or 4.0 being install via Windows update as we have not updated the software.

On my PC here the app (with some tweaks) runs fine from Visual Studio 2008 but if I use the WIX Setup project to create an installer and install the software I even get the same error running the project from my PC.

Any idea how I can debug the program and find out whats causing the error? (Ive inherited the solution so the WIX side of things is a bit lost on me, but it seems straight forward)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is related to the `supportedRuntime` setting. Find the `dtf.chm` file in your WiX installation, and get acquainted with the topic "Specifying the Runtime Version". Afterwards explicitly set the version(s) of the runtime your custom action should run on.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but Im not sure if WIX is to blame directly. I have checked the WIX config and it is doing a test for .Net framework 3.5 which is clearly passing. So it sounds like it is actually a framework dependency that is getting it wrong